# Git push, pushes successfully but puts a massive ASCII 'X' in the output

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've just pushed some code up to BitBucket, it seems to have pushed successfully but the response I got was, is, *strange*.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 924 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: ++++                               ++++
remote:   +++++++                     +++++++
remote:      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
remote:          +++++++++++++++++++++
remote:                 +++++++
remote:       +++                     +++
remote:       ++++++     +++++     ++++++
remote:        ++++++    +++++    ++++++
remote:        +++++++    +++    +++++++
remote:         ++++++++   +   ++++++++
remote:          ++++++++     ++++++++
remote:            ++++++++ +++++++++
remote:             +++++++++++++++
remote:              +++++++++++++
remote:                +++++++++
remote:                  +++++++
remote:               +   +++++++
remote:              +++   +++++++
remote:             ++++++  +++++++
remote:            +++++++   +++++++
remote:           +++++++     +++++++
remote:          +++++++       +++++++
remote:          +++++++       +++++++
remote:          +++++++       +++++++
To git@bitbucket.org:BanksySan/swag-challenge-1.git
   26ce354..86b24a4  master -> master
```

What's the giant ASCII cross for?

Comment: It's just a custom message that the server sends back. Doesn't mean anything. They're just showing off.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it's a think [they do](https://twitter.com/lefflerjacob/status/578048561360711680).

Comment: That's not "X", that's a rendering of the Atlassian logo. (An actual X would really be an improvement, IMNSHO.)

Comment: I asked this before seeing SO's own tribute to the news.  It looks cooler in colour.

Comment: @tripleee, yup, it is.  That question's got techni-colour as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is just arbitrary text that is sent from the server; the client just displays what the server sends. Note that every line is prefixed with `remote`. It is usually used for error messages, or just some informational text about the server.

In this case, it appears to be the [Atlassian Logo](https://design.atlassian.com/2.0/brand/logo/), as Atlassian is the company that owns Bitbucket. Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket), it looks like this is intended to be colored using ANSI escape sequences as a rainbow, likely to celebrate today's [Supreme Court's decision](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf) to [strike down laws against gay marriage in the US](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/27/us/supreme-court-same-sex-marriage.html?_r=0). It may be the case that your terminal is not interpreting those escape sequences, and so you are just seeing the monochrome logo, rather than the rainbow.

[image: Atlassian Logo]

Comment: Color version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not very cool there is no explanation whatsoever, just the logo. We were 100% sure for a while we've been compromised somehow.

Comment: Pretty annoying from the point of view that we expect certain output from git pushes in our CI tool ... "well screw your CI tool buddy .. here's my big X that you never asked for" ... very unprofessional

Comment: @MichaelMügge: absolutely. I upvoted your comment. I was (and am) considering downvoting the "answer" for being off-topic.

Comment: @davernator In what way is the answer off topic? It describes where the text is coming from, Bitbucket's servers, and what it indicates, support for the Supreme Court ruling on marriage equality.

Is there some other information missing from the answer that I could add?

Comment: @MichaelMügge Git repositories can send back arbitrary text that is expected to be displayed on the terminal. This can be used to indicate specific error messages that might be server specific, for instance authentication or access control errors. You can easily distinguish such messages by the fact that the lines are prefixed with `remote:`, so you can ignore them if you want to.

Comment: @BrianCampbell .. "This can be used to indicate specific error messages" ... this is the whole point. Don't you get it?  We **expect** it to be something **important and relevant**.  So when my CI tool pages me at 2am and its in fact a problem, and I fix it, I can happily get back to sleep knowing I saved the day for the devs on the other side of the globe. However when my pager goes off at 2am for some irrelevant propaganda .. I'm gonna be miffed. We are dumping BitBucket in favor of a more predictable, consistent offering that does not get cute from time to time.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: The question is about the extra output from git push. The Atlassian Logo is not the output I get, when this happens, but it looks similar. In any event, this posting in particular, and stackoverflow in general, is about the operation of technical tools, and the expectation of consistent behavior ... not speculation as to political message.

Comment: @davernator The question asks "What's the giant ASCII cross for?" I explain that it's simply arbitrary text sent from the server, then explain what that text indicates; it can sometimes be hard to recognize something in ASCII-art form, some people might not be able to see the colors, and some people might not know the context for the colors. Since the original question, they have changed from the Atlassian logo to the Bitbucket logo, but the basic answer is still the same. Does including both the technical explanation and an interpretation of the symbol make the answer off-topic?

Comment: I should note that I am not affiliated with Atlassian or Bitbucket in any way; I am simply explaining where this output comes from and what it means. The fact that servers can send arbitrary text, and that that text is sometimes just a banner image or logo of some sort, is something that can happen when using Git, and while you might want to complain to your provider if you don't like it, if you want to write robust tooling, you should not expect to be able to interpret any output prefixed with `remote` unless it's documented by your hosting provider.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: Good points. I upvoted your answer, based on your commentary, which I also upvoted.