# Why bitbucket send me a big 'X' notation after pushing?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Does anyone know why I received a big notation as shown below after pushing code? Thanks.

[image: bitbucket remote message]

Comment: That's the shaman of the plus. Don't worry. its a good omen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was there an Atlassian icon in my shell when I pushed a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649355/why-was-there-an-atlassian-icon-in-my-shell-when-i-pushed-a-commit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atlassian "logo" after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [this answer from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082114/2344348).

It is the same date (range) right now, they are celebrating the second anniversary of the declaration of same sex marriage as a legal right in the US.

The 'X' is 'Atlas holding up Earth' from the Atlassian logo. Atlassian are the company behind bitbucket.org and various other products.

[image]

If you have a terminal with color capabilities, then it should be colored with the colors of the pride flag.

Comment: Ordinarily I would not repost an answer I have already given [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649529/2344348) - but the answers already given in this thread are incomplete in my opinion and do not reflect 'why' this is showing up all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

This "X" is the Atlassian logo, the company which own BitBucket. check here : https://www.atlassian.com/

Comment: Any ideas in what circumstances it happens? Did another push after seeing this but didn't see the logo again.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's pure Atlassian hype :) It might happen only once when you push for the first time. It doesn't mean anything about your code or your repository. Basically it means "welcome on BitBucket for the first time".

Answer (score 1):

It's a new feature, it's the atlassian logo.