# git push leaving a strange text image before the line with the View Pull Request

Tags: git, image, bitbucket

When I push new code up to bitbucket I am currently seeing a text based image that looks a bit like the bit bucket logo. I am wondering 
a. how did I cause this to happen
b. how can I stop it from showing

thanks in advance.!!!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atlassian "logo" after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket)

Answer (score 1):

It is already described at [Atlassian "logo" after pushing to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081919/atlassian-logo-after-pushing-to-bitbucket/31082114#31082114) how to disable that feature. Just uncheck the option “Enable console messages” in your account settings.

Comment: Thanks Tobias.. I figured it was something I had done inadvertently.