# How to disable spam from github?

Tags: github

When I did `git push` I received the following console output:

```
Enumerating objects: 5440, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5440/5440), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1428/1428), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5440/5440), 2.00 MiB | 454.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5440 (delta 4009), reused 5440 (delta 4009)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4009/4009), done.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/igor-liferenko/delete-this/pull/new/master
remote: 
To github.com:igor-liferenko/delete-this
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

The question is how to configure my github profile to disable the following part?

```
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/igor-liferenko/delete-this/pull/new/master
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. Does it really bother you so much? Calling this "spam" is a bit much IMO.

Comment: @Chris I always read *all* console output carefully, and I absolutely detest when it is littered with rubbish. Spam is ``unsolicited message''. This is what it is. If it cannot be disabled, I'm definitely moving to some other site.

Comment: Of course you're free to move to whatever service you want, but at the end of the day this output isn't something that you control (unless you're running the service yourself). Bitbucket, for example, is known to [show a rainbow Atlassian logo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31081919/354577) to celebrate diversity around June. As the accepted answer on that question says, the server "can send arbitrary text back that is displayed on your terminal. This is frequently used for error messages, information on the server you are pushing to, or the like."

Comment: In this case, the server is (helpfully, IMO) telling you how you can request to have your branch merged to `master` using Pull Requests. This is a common workflow. My advice is to get over it.

Comment: (I still don't think this is spam. When you push you're going to get a response back from the server. The message isn't unsolicited; you just don't like everything it contains. Calling this "spam" is exactly the same as saying "Sent from my iPhone" in an email is "spam", even when it is included in an otherwise useful message.)

Comment: @Chris Anyway, `git request-pull` is the proper tool for making pull requests. And I feed irritated when I'm advised the wrong ways. It is very, very bad that user cannot control via his github profile the kind of messages he wishes to be displayed.

Comment: @Chris (I think the most feasible way to cope with this, is to recompile `git` locally, so that it just ignores this stuff)

Comment: Except that output can (and often does) contain important information. You'll be shooting yourself in the foot because you can't get over an arguably helpful message. This _is not_ "very, very bad". `git request-pull` is great, but outside of certain circles GitHub's PR model is much more widely used. One isn't objectively "proper" and the other "wrong". Anyway, I suspect if this conversation continues much longer we're going to get into a philosophical debate over nuance, which is about as off-topic as we can get. I'm done here. Good luck with however you choose to proceed.